# How can i get url path from meteor server?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to access url path from meteor server side, tried meteor absoluteurl but it doesn't get url path

Comment: Can you get more detailing on your question? What URL path do you need on the server? The one that the browser is pointing to ?

Answer (score 1):

In Meteor, the routing is generally performed on the client side via a router package.

Therefore, naturally the server has no knowledge of the URL the user's browser is currently on. If you need to have this on the server, you will need to plug into the router (or the history API) and send those yourself to the server and come up with a mechanism to store and retrieve them.